# const dependent names returned from template functions, where does const go?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, dependent-name

Suppose that I have a template function (e.g., `foo`), that returns a `const` dependent type. The options to qualify the return type as `const` is to either put const at the left of `typename` keyword:

```
template<typename T>
const typename T::bar
^^^^^
foo(T const& baz) {
  ...
}
```

or at the right of the dependent type:

```
template<typename T>
typename T::bar const
                ^^^^^
foo(T const& baz) {
  ...
}
```

But what if I put the `const` qualifier between the `typename` keyword and the dependent type?

```
template<typename T>
typename const T::bar
         ^^^^^
foo(T const& baz) {
  ...
}
```

The above as expected, fails to compile for GCC and CLANG, but to my surprise VC++ compiles it fine.

### Q:

- Is this a VC++ extension?
- Does the C++ standard say anything about where is the appropriate place to put `const` qualifier in such a context?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Does the C++ standard says anything about where is the appropriate
>   place to put `const` qualifier in such a context?

Yes. `typename` appears in a *typename-specifier*, [whose production is](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#3)

> `typename` *nested-name-specifier* *identifier* 
>    `typename` *nested-name-specifier* `template`<sub>opt</sub> *simple-template-id*

In other words, it must be followed directly by a *nested-name-specifier*. `const` is not allowed.